# private and public, how to make it work properly? -> C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, private, public

I have been trying to make the `string name;` private. I left the correct font below without putting the "string name"; in particular. Well, all attempts failed to put the "string name; private. Does anyone know how I could do this correctly. I'm new to C++ and object-oriented programming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Aluno
{
```

I would like to put `string nome;` in private, but it is not the same other functions

```
public:
    string nome;
    void setIda(int age)
    {
        if (age > 0 && age < 60)
            idade = age;
        else
            idade = 0;
    }
    int getIda()
    {
        return idade;
    }
    void setMatr(int matr)
    {
        if (matr > 0 && matr <= 1000)
            matricula = matr;
        else
            matricula = 0;
    }
    int getMatr()
    {
        return matricula;
    }
```

I would like call `string nome;` here

```
private:
    int matricula;
    int idade;
};
```

However, how could I call the functions `string nome;` in the int main()?

```
int main()
{
    Aluno *novo_aluno1 = new Aluno();
    Aluno *novo_aluno2 = new Aluno();

    novo_aluno1->nome = "John Smith";
    novo_aluno1->setIda(32);
    novo_aluno1->setMatr(999);

    novo_aluno2->nome = "Mary Smith";
    novo_aluno2->setIda(21);
    novo_aluno2->setMatr(998);

    cout << "\nNome: " << novo_aluno1->nome << "\n";
    cout << "Idade: " << novo_aluno1->getIda() << "\n";
    cout << "Matricula: " << novo_aluno1->getMatr() << "\n";

    cout << "\nNome: " << novo_aluno2->nome << "\n";
    cout << "Idade: " << novo_aluno2->getIda() << "\n";
    cout << "Matricula: " << novo_aluno2->getMatr() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What isn't the same? you don't have a `setNome` or `getNome` (yet)?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. The entire point of making members private or protected is so that they are, well, private or protected. Which means they cannot be accessed from outside the class.

Comment: Aside: `Aluno novo_aluno1; Aluno novo_aluno2;` and changing `->` for `.` would function, you don't need `new`

Comment: Thanks, @Caleth! I changed the final code and it is works.

Comment: @bitmask! you are right. However, the only var that I tried put in the private" string nome;"  doesn't work. I am not sure if I am doing correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A private parameter is only accesible from the class it is declared in.
If you want to be able to get or set the information stored in a private field you have to make what we call (public) getters and setters methods.

```cpp
private:
   std::string nome;
```

```cpp
public:
   std::string get_nome()
   {
      return this->nome;
   }

   void set_nome(std::string var)
   {
      this->nome = var;
   }
```

Then your setters and getters can be called in main()

Answer (score 1):

If you make string nome private then you can't access it in main. You can get it in the same way you got other strings by creating a public function and return the value of nome.